# Why doesn't shell() function work in Mac OS R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run shell function on R that runs some DOS exe file but my R prompt says that `shell()` does not exist. Is there any substitute function that replaces `shell()` in Mac OS?

Comment: not sure an exe would run on mac anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `system()` command as [discussed here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html). Note, though, that your mac OS will not be able to natively run an exe

Comment: Also worth noting that on OSX if you actually try to read the documentation for `?shell` to see why it might not be working, it takes you directly to `?system`.